# how to create a content type and have a multi parent content type

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, inheritance

How can i create a multi parent content type for content type :
this, its not allowed :

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Parent ContentType: CT_F(0x01008B26D252 542D4B8990E6539BC0738C91) -->
  <!-- Parent ContentType: CT_L (0x0100C880BDDEEDEC4F6289CA6DC9F5B8905C) -->
  <!-- Parent ContentType: CT_B(0x01009784194E1FC0404687CFEC06E577FC45009165988D368F4071925035877B8AB615) -->


  <ContentType ID="0x01008B26D252542D4B8990E6539BC0738C9100594BFAFB368E49FC920B8E1F780D199E"
               Name="CT_P"
               Group="Custom Content Types"
               Description="My Content Type"
               Inherits="TRUE"
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible Content type can only have 1 parent. What you could do is to have ContentType3 (CT3) inheriting from CT2 and CT2 Inherit from CT1. This way CT3 will inherit both CT2 and CT1 properties.

Comment: is there a possibility to grouping content types ?

Comment: Yes the property Group="Custom Content Types" is doing it.